# I can't seem to get audio to work in my app? I'm using AVAudio framework

Tags: audio, avaudioplayer, audio-player

Help guys :) I've tried absolutely everything to get the audio with AVAudioPlayer to work in my app. For some reason it will not play on the iPhone simulator. The code is as follows-

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myProgressView;
@synthesize sliderVolumeOutlet;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"audioapp" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];

    NSError *error;

    avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    [avPlayer setNumberOfLoops:1];

    [avPlayer setVolume:self.sliderVolumeOutlet.value];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];    
}
```

The song itself is in the project file, I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the error and try it

```
-(IBAction) playAudio{
        NSError *error;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.audioName];

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play]; 
}
```

Comment: Apologies if not an Xcode question. I am very new to this and am just trying to experiment :) Thanks for replying

Comment: Sorry guys just need some clarification here. I'm not getting any errors but the sound still won't play in the simulator. Could it be something in the .h file where I set the buttons? The code for that is-


`@interface ViewController : UIViewController 


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *myProgressView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderVolumeOutlet;
- (IBAction)sliderVolumeAction:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)pauseButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender;

@end`

Thanks for your help :)